# How can I disable internet access for docker containers

Tags: networking, docker, sandbox, ubuntu-15.04

I'm trying to run untrusted code inside a docker container and prohibit internet access for it.

I've already tried `iptables -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j DROP`

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Result of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Result of `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              VIRTUAL SIZE
virtual_machine            latest              5f2b8cea6752        3 months ago         2.795 GB
chug/ubuntu14.04x64        latest              81b68b976893        2.087208 years ago   224.7 MB
```

Find the project for reference [here](https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox)

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: @JFMeier I've already tried `iptables -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j DROP`. It gives me `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`